# Qml components not loaded properly on xcb platform

Tags: qt, x11, egl, xcb

I'm trying to run an application on xcb platform over iMx6 (qt 5.12.8), unfortunately some qml objects are not rendered correctly for example components which requires qtgraphicaleffects. I suspect that the reason for this strange behavior is a wrong cross-compilation of qt libraries, in fact no matter I change configure parameters, I'm not able to enable EGL on X11 which should solve my issue.
If I enable qt libs verbose configure I read:

egl-x11.cpp:49:9: error: invalid conversion from ‘EGLNativeDisplayType {aka void*}’ to ‘Display* {aka _XDisplay*}’ [-fpermissive]
dpy = egldpy;

```
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. yes
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... yes
    EGLFS GBM ............................ yes
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    LinuxFB ................................ no
    VNC .................................... yes
    Mir client ............................. no
```

Someone faced the same issue? How could be solved? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering to my own question for whom may face the same problem. I was compiling qt using a sysroot configured to run with Vivante plugin for video acceleration. That was not compatible with eglfs on x11. Without egl , qt libraries are not able to render correctly complex objects such as those mentioned in the question. Compiling with the right dependencies and running with eglfs solved the issue.